# Hi I want to count the number of times a record appears

Tags: sql

for ex. if Row Key 5 shows up 3 times, the first record would return 1, second 2, and third 3

Comment: What database and version? They can **significantly** impact your options for this question.

Comment: Welcome to SO (Stack Overflow), please add some code or expand this question, it will help SO community answer your query. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by rowkey order by <ordering col>)
from t;
```

`<ordering col>` is the column that defines "first", "second", and so on.